# Please How can I convert sql query into laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to convert this sql query into laravel query builder or how can I run into laravel as it is.

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms,IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms), 0) as "reserved rooms", rt.total_no_of_rooms - IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms),0) as "rooms available" FROM Rooms rt LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservations r ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id  AND  '2020-04-04' >=  r.check_in AND  '2020-04-02' <=  r.check_out GROUP BY rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I run into laravel as it is.

There is this approach:

```
$query= DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms,IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms), 0) as 'reserved rooms', rt.total_no_of_rooms - IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms),0) as 'rooms available' FROM Rooms rt LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservations r ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id  AND  '2020-04-04' >=  r.check_in AND  '2020-04-02' <=  r.check_out GROUP BY rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms"));
```

It will simply run the query. You can foreach the $query now.

Comment: Maybe a nice addition: If you need Eloquent models from this, you can use the 'hydrate' method on your model, pass it in the result of the query and you should get a collection with models.